# Creating an energy weapon via (something) using electromagnetic fields

Tags: science-based, weapons, spaceships

Using whatever means, you collect particles of some description matter that would normally repel itself to instead attract. Containing it in a massive electromagnetic field that continues to suck in more matter and compress it, **would you end up with enough energized matter that could be expelled as a weapon?**

Working with that idea, said electromagnets would contain the matter within it's chamber until it was time to release the energy, allowing for a build in intensity. The same electromagnets could weaken and allow a tiny funnel for the energy to fly out and strike a target at range.

I imagine the emitted beam of energized molecules would disperse quickly, so lets toss in the stipulation that **very specific molecules fuse together in a by product of process and act as a semi-coherent guide for the energy**. However the beam would still dissipate quite rapidly.

I imagine this might look like a miniature star like reaction that is then propelled forward, kind of like how a water gun works. Compress and then expel.

I am assuming the following in this process:

- The level of technology would exist to do this
- The required power is available
- If extra material is required it can be injected into the chamber

**What basis could be used to generate such an effect? Am I simply talking about a massive particle cannon?**

Comment: Actually the electromagnetic field holds the matter together; what stops it from collapsing is quantum mechanics, specifically the Pauli principle (preventing several particles from occupying the same state) and the uncertainty relation (making confining of a single particle in a too small space energetically expensive).

Comment: So if I instead made it work by negating the Pauli principle in order to compress energized matter, would that be acceptable?

Comment: I think locally reducing Planck's constant (by claiming it to actually be a field that can be manipulated) would be more credible. A smaller Planck's constant would shrink matter, but I'm not sure what forces it would cause on matter entering/leaving that area. Given that it would increase the inner energy of the atoms, I suspect it would case a force expelling the atoms from that area. Thinking again about it, maybe your electromagnetic reversal *could* actually suck matter in, through an indirect effect: By making the proton-proton interaction attractive, the nucleus binding energy would …

Comment: … grow, making the nucleus *less* energetic and thus creating a force that sucks the atoms in (but not through atom-atom interaction, but simply because the nuclei can release some of their energy inside). Also I notice that the atoms could indeed shrink a bit, despite the Pauli effect, because the inner electrons no longer would screen the charge of the nucleus, but rather would add to it.

Comment: However, the process of reversing the effect of Coulomb interaction would be quite far outside anything possible by realistic physics, so I'd still advice to think about manipulating other things (like the Higgs field, or hypothetical fields affecting constants like electron charge, speed of light, or Planck's constant). That's still outside current physics, but at least not *that* far outside physics (manipulating the Higgs field would be closest to real physics, as that is a field that is known to exist, so it's not a big stretch to assume we find ways to manipulate it).

Comment: @celtschk Great info, I will make some changes to the idea once I get a chance

Comment: How the heck do you propose to change the value of the constant? It's impossible.

Comment: @hde226868 Then what do you suggest? I already tried the coulomb force, perhaps I should just mention planck's law? Or divert focus to the higgs field? Or as celtschk mentioned, simply temporarily reducing Planck's constant by using a massive electromagnetic field?

Comment: @Nonafel You can't have technology that changes any of these things. They're fundamental laws of nature.

Comment: The issue I have with this that since the weapon gets its energy from "projectile" being compressed by external force, I do not see how it could outperform a mass driver shooting nuclear warheads. Regardless of the exotic method you use to compress matter, applying energy **directly** to accelerate projectile with mass driver should always give better muzzle velocity and accuracy. And releasing energy **directly** at target should always have less dispersion and superior energy efficiency.

Comment: @HDE226868: First note that this doesn't have a hard-science tag. Second, don't confuse our theories with the universe: In the nineteenth century, it was a "law of nature" that time goes independent from whatever happens in it, and everyone who had seriously claimed that you can slow your ageing by moving around really fast would have been laughed at, because you know, it's against the laws of physics. And thirdly, note that there are *actual real world scientists* who look for signatures of changes of fundamental constants in astronomical data.

Comment: @celtschk Regarding the points: 1) Yes, I know, but posts on Worldbuilding should follow science to some extent, especially when using the [tag:science-based] tag. 2) I know, but you could apply that principle to lots of things. 3) Yes, I'm well aware of those theories. But I don't think that many of those scientists think that we could actually *change* those constants.

Answer (score 2):

So let's ignore that it isn't possible to change the value of the Planck Constant ($\hbar$) since to do so require a developing a technology that can reach outside this universe then come back in and alter fundamental properties. And if such a technology is possible then all bets are off and the author can do whatever they want without regards to plausibility. This kind of tech *is* magic.

Assuming that the Planck Constant can be changed, what would happen? From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_constant):

> The Planck–Einstein relation now describes the energy of each photon in terms of the photon's frequency. This energy is extremely small in terms of ordinary experience.

Based on nothing other than that statement, reducing the value of the Planck Constant would make a weapon less powerful or at least less inefficient than a weapon without a manipulated value of $\hbar$. And weird things would happen at the interface between the normal value of $\hbar$ and a manipulated value.

If anything, you would want to increase the value of $\hbar$ to pack more energy into each photon though conservation of energy and thermodynamics will prevent you from getting more energy back than you put in.

In general, this is a bad idea. What happens if the value of $\hbar$ goes too high and can't be maintained? What if it forms in an absolute reference frame that won't move along with the rest of space? It's just too weird for a science-based story.